# How can I build my application using Pyinstaller on M1 architecture when 2 of the required dylibs are built on x86 architecture?

Tags: python-3.x, x86, pyinstaller, apple-m1, dynamic-library

I am in a situation for the past couple of days and need your help.
Lets say my application has 10 dylibs as dependency, but 2 of which was built on mac x86 architecture and the remaining 8 are built using m1

Is there anyway to build my application in M1? I tried using pyinstaller but its throwing me an assertion error that states the x86 library cannot be used in M1 architecture

Note: I dont have an option to build the x86 library in m1 since its a third party and we have lost support from them.

Tried using Pyinstaller 4.5 and Python 395 for bundling but no lead on that